# SQL ORDER BY number of rows?

Tags: sql

How do you ORDER BY number of rows found in another table? I have a table for animals (these are livestock animals) and another table for awards. When an animal wins an award, the award gets added to the awards table.

People want to be able to find the animals who have won the most awards (WHERE award type is 1), ordered from most awards to least. How do I ORDER BY how many awards they have if the awards are in a separate table each with their own row?

```
SELECT animals.id 
FROM animals 
  LEFT JOIN awards ON animals.id = awards.animalid 
WHERE awards.type = 1 
ORDER BY...
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a tag with the database you are using.

Comment: Unrelated, but: your `where` clause on the outer joined table (`awards`)  turns the outer join into an inner join

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT a.id
FROM animals a LEFT JOIN
     awards aw
     ON a.id = aw.animalid AND aw.type = 1 
GROUP BY a.id
ORDER BY COUNT(aw.animalid) DESC;
```

Comment: This did it! Thank you.